# Toroidal compactification and number of susy

Tags: string-theory, compactification

In case of Tordial compactification, 
reference states [page 13, A.Font et al, Introduction to string compactification](http://www.aei.mpg.de/~theisen/lectures.ps), it does not reduce the number of real supercharges.

I wonder why this happens.

Further i want to know during the compactification when does the number of susy changes ($i.e$, when the supersymmetry broken happens)